# TypeScript / JavaScript - How to get superclass of a class?

Tags: javascript, reflection, typescript, superclass, introspection

Let's say I have:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {}
var clazz = Bar;
```

I figured out that to get `Bar` there's `clazz.prototype.constructor`.

How can I find out what is the parent class of `Bar`?

Comment: I think you meant `obj.constructor === Bar`, since `obj.prototype === undefined`

Comment: Right. I've changed the question to focus on the classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented on the answer by @MattiasBuelens, it should be: `obj.constructor` and not `obj.prototype.constructor` as `obj.prototype` is null (the `prototype` property exists on the class `Bar` but not the instances).

As for getting the constructor of `Foo`, well this is an ugly hack:

```
let FooCtor = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)).constructor;
var foo = new FooCtor();
```

---

#### Edit

If you want to do the same thing but with the `Bar` class instead of instance of it, then:

```
let FooCtor = Object.getPrototypeOf(Bar.prototype).constructor;
var foo = new FooCtor();
```

Comment: No, if you don't add the `constructor` part and only do this: `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))` then it gives you an `Object`, but add the `constructor` and you'll get the `Foo`. Just copy what I did exactly and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript 1.8 uses this to extend a class (reduced here for readability):

```
var __extends = function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};

var TestPlanetModel = (function (_super) {
    __extends(TestPlanetModel, _super);
    function TestPlanetModel() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return TestPlanetModel;
}(FrameModel));
```

Which uses local `Function` to instantiate the prototype, and that hides the relation between the two classes in that closure.

Thanks to Nitzan for the trick, I only needed to check the class, not the object, so I instantiate it to get to the prototype:

```
var clazz = TestPlanetModel;
var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(new clazz())).constructor;
alert(parent === FrameModel);
```

I didn't figure out how to do it without instantiating.

Comment: I'm not sure why you posted this answer. You add nothing over my answer. If you want to ask how to do this without instantiating then you can either post a comment on my question or edit your question.

Comment: I did :) Check the question

Comment: No, you provide more details in an answer and not in your question. Basically you took my solution, posted it as your own answer and then asked in that answer how to do it with the class instead of the instance. If you'd only asked that question in a comment to my answer then I'd answer it, but what incentive do I have to answer it now after you posted my solution as your own answer?

Comment: I have updated the question and you did not reply. So I figured out and answered. Update your answer and I can accept. Sorry if you feel any harm from this.

Comment: This isn't just about accepting the answer, it's also about not having duplications in answers for future readers. In any case, I updated my answer with how to do it with the class instead of an instance.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released an enhanced version of the TypeScript compiler that lets you know all the reflection metadata of classes and interfaces, both at coding time and runtime. The following code suits your needs:

```
class MySuper {
    id: number;
    constructor(n: number) {
        console.log("MySuper instantiated with param: " + n);
        this.id = n;
    }
}

class MySub extends MySuper {
    name: string;
}


let sub: Class = MySub.getClass();
if(sub.extends) {
    let superCtor = sub.extends.getConstructor<MySuper>(); //type param is optional, you can get "any" by default.
    //let's instantiate it!!!
    let superObj = new superCtor(3);
    console.log("superObj.id = " + superObj.id);
}
```

and this is the output:

```
$ node main.js
MySuper instantiated with param: 3
superObj.id = 3
```

You can find my project [here](https://github.com/pcan/reflec-ts).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Object.getPrototypeOf (AnyClass)"
to return the super-class of AnyClass:

```
 class Foo {}
 class Bar extends Foo {};

 let SuperClassOfBar = Object.getPrototypeOf (Bar);
 if (SuperClassOfBar === Foo)
 { console.log 
    (`Superclass of Bar is Foo`);  // yes it is
 }
```